# How many languages does .Net support?

Tags: .net

How many languages does the latest versions of Visual Studio (2012 and 2010) support?

Also, is it possible to create a new language in .Net?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages

Comment: http://www.dotnetpowered.com/languages.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 directly support C#, VB.Net, C++/CLI, and F# for .NET development.  There are many other languages with various levels of "support" as well, including IronRuby and IronPython, Boo, etc.

Anybody is free to make their own language on top of the CLI, and many have done so.  [Wikipedia has a fairly long list of .NET languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages).

Answer (score 2):

At least C#, F#, IronPython, Visual Basic.NET, C++ (and also a "hidden" C compiler I believe as well), at the minimum.

In addition, support for HTML5, Javascript, CSS3, etc.